# How to print a log based on a driver current URL in Python

Tags: python, selenium, printing, automation, driver

Currently working on a small project to get the hang of automation and was wondering how to go about printing a status showing logged in once the url redirects to a certain page

```
if a is "https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#choose-address"
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Logged in!")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=current_url#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url

```
if driver.current_url is "https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#choose-address"
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Logged in!")
```

Refer the python classes ,if you refer webdriver remote class you can is there is an inbuild current_url property that will give the current url of the page

Comment: I'm still confused so what should I do? For example I need to check the status of the entry. My code is as follows

if "https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#unlucky" in driver.current_url:
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Non winner, retrying entry")
    if "https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#winner" in driver.current_url:
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Winner!, check your email.")

It's not printing the current status though.

Answer (score 0):

`is` will return **`True`** if two variables point to the same object. Where as `==` will return **`True`** if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

> You can find a detailed relevan discussion in [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

---

### Solution

As a solution you can validate the string `https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#choose-address` with in the string returned through `driver.current_url` as follows:

```
if "https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#choose-address" in driver.current_url:
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Logged in!")
```

A optimal approach validate the partial string `choose-address` with in the string returned through `driver.current_url` as follows:

```
if "choose-address" in driver.current_url:
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Logged in!")
```

Comment: @Daniel Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Got it but for some reason when I am completing the giveaway in the browser the current URL is matching the code I have currently.


```if 'https://pepsi.fooji.com/?#unlucky' in driver.current_url:
    rint(f"[{datetime.now()}] - Non winner, retrying...")```

Comment: It's not printing the current status

Comment: @Daniel _`Non winner, retrying...`_ sounds like a different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.